# How do I find out the AppID of what created a toast notification?

Tags: powershell, uwp, notifications, windows-10, toast

I want to find out the AppId of programs that have made toast notifications recently.  I'm using PowerShell, but would probably be fine seeing examples in C# and other languages if necessary.

In PowerShell, one can use `Get-StartApps` to get a list of AppIds for every app.  Examining that list for something that visually matches is a workaround, but is there a better way to get which specific apps just toasted?

There are promising-sounding methods like [ToastNotificationManager.History.GetHistory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotificationhistory.gethistory#Windows_UI_Notifications_ToastNotificationHistory_GetHistory) but it requires a specific tag, which I also don't know how to get.

I used `ToastNotificationManager.History.Clear` as a proof of concept:

```
[Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
[Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null

[Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::History.Clear('Microsoft.XboxApp_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.XboxApp')
```

This clears all notifications from the Xbox app, for example.  I adapted this from the answer to [Win 10 app: remove toast notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901652/win-10-app-remove-toast-notification) and some trial and error...  After not being able to figure out the tag, I saw that [History.Clear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotificationhistory.clear#Windows_UI_Notifications_ToastNotificationHistory_Clear_System_String_) could be passed an AppId instead.

That's fine if all I wanted to do is apply it to a specific installed app (if indeed searching `Get-StartApps` is the only way to get its AppId).  But even then, what if it's not on the list, like built in to Windows, for example "Security and Maintenance"?  How do I get that AppId?

(If anyone knows how to get the tag of a toast, that'd be nice to know as well.)

Answer (score 1):

App IDs for notifications appear to be stored in: HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings

Remember to run this as the user that launched the notification. This will only give you the first part of the ID - but its a start.